# How to remove more than 1 slashes from url and create new route in VueJs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Here are the thing
A Bad Url could be 
`https://rajesh.com//settings/myworklog/edit//136`  
`https://rajesh.com//settings/myworklog/edit//136`  
`https://rajesh.com///settings//myworklog/edit////136`  
I want this to be change as

`https://rajesh.com/settings/myworklog/edit/136` 

and assign into route and navigate next.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const { meta: { authorize: authorize }, name } = to;
  
  // check if 
  console.log('to', to.fullPath)
  console.log('to fullPath', to.fullPath.replace(/(?<!:)\/+/gm, '/'))
  console.log('next', next)
  to['fullPath'] = to.fullPath.replace(/(?<!:)\/+/gm, '/'); // want something like this as to is read-only object it will not work here.
  
  next();
})
```

can anyone guide me here?
Thanks

Comment: Try something like `to.fullPath.replace(/([^:]\/)\/+/g, "$1");`

Comment: @GuidoFaecke not worked. did not replace main URL.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution could be:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const { meta: { authorize: authorize }, name } = to;
  to.fullPath = to.fullPath
    .replaceAll('//', '/')
    .replace(':/', '://');

  next();
})
```

Comment: main issue here is reassigning or replacing current URL with correct URL.